# OrgLimits.getMap() Causes System.UnexpectedException when Packaging

Tags: limits

I am building a beta package and have added a class with this line of code in it (referred to as line 19 in the error below:

```
Map<String, System.OrgLimit> limitsMap = OrgLimits.getMap();
```

When the unit tests execute as part of the packaging process the unit test fails on the above line with the following nasty error:

```
System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 451499716-1404310 (-2071874720) (-2071874720)

(System Code) Class.rtms.PerformanceIQManager.getOrgLimits: line 19, column 1 Class.rtms.PerformanceIQController.getOrgLimits: line 47, column 1 Class.rtms.UnitTestsControllers17.testPerformanceIQController1: line 802, column 1
```

Clearly the execution of unit tests in a packaging org is barking at the Limits access for some reason.....  Is there a permission somewhere that I need to set?  The unit test works fine in dev/source orgs.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I have fought with this problem all day.  What I have concluded is that if OrgLimits.getMap() (or getAll or anything like that) gets called in an API version higher than 55 in a synchronous test context then it will fail like this.  If I take the tests above API v55 an run they async they work, but I think that tests during packaging are forced to run synchronously so the only thing to do is make the call in an API v55 class.

Comment: To prove out the sync vs async thing I was able to make the test fail in the Dev Console when I ran it synchronously but it passed running asynchronously.

Comment: Wow, thanks, Stephen that is very interesting.